# jqGrid FormEditing beforeShowForm align left

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

My modal `FormEditing` windows appears centered.

[image: FormEditing window]

In order to overcome this, I have used

```
 beforeShowForm: function(formId) {
     $(formId).attr('align', 'left');
 }
```

This works fine in Chrome, but not in Firefox. Any better idea than using `beforeShowForm`? Have I missed a property for setting the alignment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have some CSS conflicts. Some CSS are applied on the edit form, which are created for absolute another place on your HTML page. It's the only reason which I see. You have to localize the style which are applied on the form and change it definition so that it will be not applied on jqGrid. Alternatively you can add another more exact style which overwrite the styles. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12298889/315935) for an example of close problems. You can use Developer Tools of Internet Explorer (press <kbd>F12</kbd> to start) Developer Tools of Google Chrome, Firebug or other tools to analyse the styles applied on the form.