# Jqgrid inline edit submits the html instead of typed text

Tags: jqgrid, inline-editing

Have the jqGrid as below, problem is that getting the input html on save, due to not focusing out of the jqgrid (may be).

```
$(mygridId).jqGrid({
        url: url,
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['ID', 'Name', 'Description'],
        colModel: [
            {
                name: 'Id',
                index: 'Id',
                hidden: true
            },
            {
                name: 'Name',
                index: 'Name',
                width: 25,
                editable: true
            },
            {
                name: 'Description',
                index: 'Description',
                width: 25,
                search: false,
                editable: true
            }
        ],
        cellEdit: true,
        rownumWidth: 40,
        gridview: true,
        sortname: "Id",
        autoencode: false,
        cellsubmit: 'clientArray',

        onCellSelect: function (rowId, iCol) {
            theRow = rowId;
            theColumn = iCol;
        },
        afterEditCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
            theColumn = iCol;
            theRow = rowid;
        },
        beforeEditCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
            theColumn = iCol;
            theRow = rowid;
        },

        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            userdata: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records"
        }
    });
    $(mygridid).jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });
```

When i add multiple rows, and click save button, focus won't be lost from the textbox, Hence, the saved value of the textbox will be

```
<input type="text" id="1_Description" name="Description" role="textbox" style="width: 98%;">
```

Any idea how to fix these?

Thanks in advace!

Comment: What do the function editRow called in onSelectRow event? How do you edit and how do you save the edited data?

Comment: Sorry, just edited the code, onSelectRow wont fire if cellEdit is set to true. I was doing on and off codes, hence missed to remove it. Saving  button exists outside the grid. On click "$("#" + gridId).getChangedCells('all');" will do this. But here it is giving the wrong data

Comment: Without any show of code it is not possible to help. This is the important part here.

Comment: I answered this same issue over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547597/jqgrid-form-edititing-html-instead-value-in-form-field/74633745?r=Saves_UserSavesList#74633745

Answer (score 0):

This is from same issue I answered elsewhere (see comments)...

This happens (sometimes) when inline (row or cell) editing is used in jqGrid. The implementation I used is https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid.

What happens is that the editor control is not cleared inside the "td" tag of the cell in the underlying "table" used by jqGrid. The cell will still show the entered/edited value once, but when the cell is entered again (clicked, tabbed, arrow keys, etc.), the text in the newly injected editor control will be the content (innerHTML?) of the "td" tag - which is the previous editor control HTML. This is what I see when this happens in both the grid and the HTML:

[image: Showing Ghost editor - td innerHTML with previous editor HTML]

Note that this HTML is the TOP 2nd cell shown in the image, with the "ghost" editor in the cell.

```
<td role="gridcell" style="text-align: center; color: black; background-color: white;" aria-describedby="Grid_Col2" class="editable-cell" title="" tabindex="0">
   <input type="text" autocomplete="off" maxlength="9" id="93_Col2" name="Col2" role="textbox" style="width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;">
</td>
```

I cannot confirm "why", but I was able to resolve this by using `setTimeout()`. I know, I know... :-( It seems to have something to do with the "navigation" div element (header element) of the grid snapping focus back to it - I guess if the currently selected control doesn't have the "edited" CSS (and the header cannot be edited...), it won't/can't fully remove the input control?

The `setTimeout()` was put in the "afterEditCell" override (see code block below).

I also gained stability by having empty implementations of the most of the cell editing override functions:

```
afterEditCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
    let rawInput = $("#" + this.id + " tbody>tr:eq(" + iRow + ")>td:eq(" + iCol + ") input, select, textarea");
    rawInput.select();
    rawInput.focus();

    setTimeout(() => {
        //TODO: I hate this, but not able to determine why focus goes back to the keyboard
        //      navigation DIV instead of the cell being edited. So, we have to force it. :(
        //      This may have something to do with the "trick" to process keydown on non-input
        //      elements: https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.celledit.js line 530
        rawInput.focus();
    }, 100);
},
afterRestoreCell: function (rowid, value, iRow, iCol) {
    console.log("afterRestoreCell: (" + iRow + ", " + iCol + ") " + value);
},
afterSaveCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
    //console.log("afterSaveCell: (" + iRow + ", " + iCol + ") " + value);
},
beforeEditCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
    //console.log("beforeEditCell: (" + iRow + ", " + iCol + ") " + value);
},
beforeSaveCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
    //console.log("beforeSaveCell: (" + iRow + ", " + iCol + ") " + value);
    return value;    // note that this is required here!
},
beforeSubmitCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
    //console.log("saving cell with value:" + value);
}
```